# WSO2 api manager jaggery extensions

Tags: wso2-api-manager, jaggery-js

In wso2 api manager we extended the store a bit with custom jaggery code. Now we would like to send an email from within the jaggery code. According to the jaggeryjs documentation this should be possible with the "new email.Sender" function. However, when using require("email") jaggery complains that that module could not be found.

I looked for it and assume it is in the jaggery extensions repo, which I downloaded and build with maven. However, now I'm at a loss what to do next and how to install those features maven built into wso2 am. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this. Can anybody guide me?

The code I use (from:http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=sender)

```
if (result) {
    try
    {
        var content = question;
        var to = ".....";
        var subject = "Question from opendata faq page";

        var email = require('email');
        var smtpSettings = jagg.module("stib").getSmtpSettings();

        log.info(smtpSettings);

        var sender = new email.Sender(smtpSettings.host, smtpSettings.port, smtpSettings.user, smtpSettings.password);

        sender.from = "....";
        sender.to = to;
        sender.cc = email;
        sender.bcc = "";
        sender.subject = subject;
        sender.text = content;
        sender.send();

        return true;
    }
    catch(error) {
        log.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error that `require('email')` cannot be found? During your build? Additionally, could you provide a link to the documentation indicating that the email module should be imported and used in this way?

Comment: In the wso2carbon log. The jaggery page throws that error.

The relevant code I use is added to the question.

Comment: the exact error I see in the logs is: Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: A module cannot be found with the specified name : email

Answer (score 0):

you can install the jaggery extension as features[1].
e.g for am 2.0.0 you can use the wilkes[1] repo and install the email module feature , this will install the jaggery extenstion

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon440/Installing+Features+via+the+UI

[2]http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem is, I can't find it in the features list. It is in the repo, I can see it, so I no it must be there. But have no idea what the feature is called. Looking for email, jaggery or extensions doesn't give me the result I'm hoping for.